# How to Extract/Scrape option values from dynamic dropdowns in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to extract the data from a Web page where the options in the dropdown lists are dynamically loaded based on our input. I am using Selenium Webdriver to extract the data from the dropdowns. Please see the screenshots below.

[Dropdown 1 - State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCNC.png)

[Dropdown 2 - City](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XCh9.png)

[Dropdown 3 - Station](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsYwc.png)

City Dropdown options are loaded once I select the state and Station dropdown is loaded after I select city.

So far I was able to get it working to extract the station names with this code.

```
citiesList = []
stationNameList = []
siteIdList = []

for city in cityOptions[1:]:
    citiesList.append(city.text)

stationDropDown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@id,'stations')]")
stationOptions = stationDropDown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')

 
      for ele in citiesList:
            cityDropdown.send_keys(ele, Keys.RETURN)
            time.sleep(2)
            stationDropDown.click()
            print(stationDropDown.text)
```

[State Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XK1l.png)

[City Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXC3U.png)

[Option values from station dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZfFM.png)

Can anyone please help me in extracting the siteId's for every state and city?

Comment: Website URL pls?

Comment: https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/

Comment: There are only station site ids available on the web site. Do you want to scrap only that or something else also?

Comment: station site ID's and  station name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach using python - **[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/)** simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to **requests**. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the API URL and payload **(very important to do a POST request)** to do a POST request and get the data in return.
2. After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
3. At last it will iterate all over the list of stations one by one and print the details like State name, City name, Station name and Station Site Id.

> Network call tab
> [image]

> Output of below code.

[image: Output of python script]

```
def scrape_aqi_site_id():
URL = 'https://app.cpcbccr.com/aqi_dashboard/aqi_station_all_india' #API URL
payload = 'eyJ0aW1lIjoxNjAzMTA0NTczNDYzLCJ0aW1lWm9uZU9mZnNldCI6LTMzMH0=' #Unique payload fetched from the network request
response = requests.post(URL,data=payload,verify=False) #POST request to get the data using URL and Payload information
result = json.loads(response.text) # parse the JSON object using json library
extracted_states = result['stations'] 
for state in range(len(extracted_states)): # loop over extracted states and its stations data.
    print('=' * 120)
    print('Scraping station data for state : ' + extracted_states[state]['stateID'])
    for station in range(len(extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'])): # loop over each state station data to get the information of stations
        print('-' * 100)
        print('Scraping data for city and its station : City (' + extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'][station]['cityID'] + ') & station (' + extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'][station]['name'] + ')')
        print('City :' + extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'][station]['cityID'])
        print('Station Name : ' + extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'][station]['name'])
        print('Station Site Id : ' + extracted_states[state]['stationsInCity'][station]['id'])
        print('-' * 100)        
    print('Scraping of data for state : (' + extracted_states[state]['stateID'] + ') is conmpleted now going for another one...')
    print('=' * 120)

scrape_aqi_site_id()
```

Comment: Thanks @Vin. Appreciate your help. The script worked for me. I couldn't find the POST url **https://app.cpcbccr.com/aqi_dashboard/aqi_station_all_india** that you've used. I've searched for it in the network tab of **https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/** for the requests.

Comment: For your reference i have added the image of my network tab. Also if that works for you please up vote and accept the answer. Thanks